# CFPDF thumbnail problem not showing background/images

Tags: pdf, thumbnails, cfpdf

I have 2 pdf's i'm running through CFPDF action="thumbnail".
The first pdf returns a perfect looking thumb.
The second returns a thumb with only the text and background colors, but NO background or foreground images.  I didn't create these PDF's, I can't tell a difference in the two.

Here's the code, simplified for testing purposes:

```
<cfpdf action="thumbnail" source="First.pdf" destination="thumbnails" overwrite="yes">
<cfpdf action="thumbnail" source="Second.pdf" destination="thumbnails" overwrite="yes">

<img src="thumbnails/First_page_1.jpg">
<img src="thumbnails/Second_page_1.jpg">
```

I can send the pdfs in question if necessary, but would rather not post them here for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If the images within the pdf page are formatted in JPEG2000 format, Coldfusion skips the image... resulting in a blank thumbnail...

[Coldfusion 8 Release Notes](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/coldfusion/8/releasenotes.pdf)

-- do a search for "thumbnail"

Dom

P.S. At least as of CF8, I haven't seen any updates in CF9 yet...